# Referencing figures with bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, cross-reference, figures, bookdown

For some reason I have problems with cross-referencing figures in a bookdown document. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

Reference example: \@ref(fig:plot-cars):

```{r plot-cars, fig.cap = "A car plot"}
plot(cars)
```
````

When I knit this, R Markdown throws the following warning ...

```
Warning message:
The label(s) fig:plot-cars not found
```

... and this result:
[image]

This problem seems to be very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156279/cross-referencing-in-a-single-file-bookdown-document), which was solved by an update of `bookdown`. As far as I understand my `session_info()` this should not be a problem any more:

```
Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
 system   i386, mingw32               
 ui       RStudio (0.99.489)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  German_Germany.1252         
 tz       Europe/Berlin               
 date     2017-01-20                  

Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package   * version date       source        
 bookdown    0.3     2016-11-28 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 devtools    1.9.1   2015-09-11 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 digest      0.6.8   2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 htmltools   0.3.5   2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.2.4)
 knitr       1.11    2015-08-14 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 memoise     0.2.1   2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 Rcpp        0.12.8  2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rmarkdown   0.8.1   2015-10-10 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
 yaml        2.1.13  2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When in doubt, `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` (it is 2017 now and you still have packages from 2014? :). Your RStudio version is also a little low but I don't think that matters in this case.

Comment: I know. This is due to the fact that, at my office, I do not have internet access from within R. Thus, it is kind of tedious to receive package updates. I hoped to get a specific hint but I guess I have to compile a list of outdated packages to be update for the responsible colleage. Still, thank you!

Comment: My best guess is that the knitr version is too low.

Comment: I managed to update all relevant packages. Now the `pandoc` version is too low for creating numbered figures. Simple documents work. 

Do I recall correctly that `pandoc` ships with RStudio?

Comment: Yes, if you have the latest version of RStudio, it should have a built-in version of Pandoc, which is 1.17.2. You can verify by `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`.

Answer (score 5):

The name of the code chunk cannot have special characters in it. I recommend using camelCase just to be sure. I.e. this should work:

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::html_document2: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r plotCars, fig.cap = "A car plot"}
plot(cars)
```

Reference example: \@ref(fig:plotCars):
````

Comment: wow apparently underscores count as special characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences this problem even upon updating all packages, check if your references are correctly specified. `??` also appear in the pdf output when referring to a chunk with a table using `\@ref(fig:missings)` rather than `\@ref(tab:missings)`. This solved it for me.