# Cross-referencing in a single-file produced with `bookdown::html_document2`

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I cannot render a figure number using `bookdown::html_document2` correctly, as [a previously solved one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38156279/10215301) claimed.

[The answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242164/10215301) confirmed that there was a bug which disabled cross-referencing function and that [*t*]*he figure number should be generated correctly if you use bookdown >= 0.0.75*. I use `bookdown` = 0.14, however, the cross-referencing function does not seem to work again, as you can tell from the figure below. Do I miss some codes to put into the `Rmd` file, or is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

[image]

## MWE

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Yamada Taro"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    toc_float: true
    number_section: true
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r}
library(fitdistrplus)
library(statmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
```


Fig. \@ref(fig:fig-data-dist)

```{r fig-data-dist}
ggdistribution(dnorm, seq(-5, 5, 0.01), mean = 0, sd = 1)
#View(l1l20_data)
```
````

## Session Info

### Platform

```
> sessioninfo::session_info()$platform
##  setting  value                       
##  version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
##  os       Windows 10 x64              
##  system   x86_64, mingw32             
##  ui       RTerm                       
##  language (EN)                        
##  collate  Japanese_Japan.932          
##  ctype    Japanese_Japan.932          
##  tz       Asia/Tokyo                  
##  date     2019-11-11
```

### Packages

```
> sessioninfo::session_info()$packages[1:47,1:10]
##  package      * version  date       lib source        
##  assertthat     0.2.1    2019-03-21 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  backports      1.1.5    2019-10-02 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  bookdown       0.14     2019-10-01 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  cli            1.1.0    2019-03-19 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  colorspace     1.4-1    2019-03-18 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  crayon         1.3.4    2017-09-16 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  digest         0.6.21   2019-09-20 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  dplyr          0.8.3    2019-07-04 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  evaluate       0.14     2019-05-28 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  fitdistrplus * 1.0-14   2019-01-23 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  ggfortify    * 0.4.8    2019-11-10 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  ggplot2      * 3.2.1    2019-08-10 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  glue           1.3.1    2019-03-12 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  gridExtra      2.3      2017-09-09 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  gtable         0.3.0    2019-03-25 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  htmltools      0.4.0    2019-10-04 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  knitr          1.25     2019-09-18 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  labeling       0.3      2014-08-23 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  lattice        0.20-38  2018-11-04 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  lazyeval       0.2.2    2019-03-15 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  lifecycle      0.1.0    2019-08-01 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  lsei         * 1.2-0    2017-10-23 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  magrittr       1.5      2014-11-22 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  MASS         * 7.3-51.4 2019-03-31 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  Matrix         1.2-17   2019-03-22 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  munsell        0.5.0    2018-06-12 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  npsurv       * 0.4-0    2017-10-14 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  pillar         1.4.2    2019-06-29 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  pkgconfig      2.0.3    2019-09-22 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  purrr          0.3.2    2019-03-15 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  R6             2.4.0    2019-02-14 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  Rcpp           1.0.2    2019-07-25 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  rlang          0.4.0    2019-06-25 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  rmarkdown      1.16     2019-10-01 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  scales         1.0.0    2018-08-09 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  sessioninfo    1.1.1    2018-11-05 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  statmod      * 1.4.32   2019-05-29 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  stringi        1.4.3    2019-03-12 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  stringr        1.4.0    2019-02-10 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  survival     * 2.44-1.1 2019-04-01 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  tibble         2.1.3    2019-06-06 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  tidyr          1.0.0    2019-09-11 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  tidyselect     0.2.5    2018-10-11 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  vctrs          0.2.0    2019-07-05 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  withr          2.1.2    2018-03-15 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
##  xfun           0.10     2019-10-01 []  CRAN (R 3.6.1)
##  yaml           2.2.0    2018-07-25 []  CRAN (R 3.6.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *must* provide a figure caption. Otherwise no figure number is created, so there is nothing to refer to. I am sure this is also mentioned in the documentation. Anyway, here a (stripped down) example:

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

Fig. \@ref(fig:fig-data-dist)

```{r fig-data-dist, fig.cap = 'Here is a plot about pressure'}
plot(pressure)
```
````